# Angular 4 For loop from API call

Tags: angular, api, typescript, http

I need help with something. 
I made an HTTP API call and it works. I am getting a list of products from the API call, but now I need to loop through them so that I can choose the "name" of them all.

This is what my Product.Service.TS looks like :

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { KioskService } from "./kiosk.service";
import { Object } from "../object";

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  private config: Object = {};
  public domainSettings: Object = {};

  constructor(private http: Http, private kioskservice: KioskService) {}

  public getAllProducts() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .get(
          `${this.kioskservice.getAPIUrl()}products/?apikey=${this.kioskservice.getAPIKey()}`
        )
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => {
            this.config = res.json();
            console.log(res.json());
            resolve();
          },
          msg => {
            throw new Error("Couldn't get all Bookings: " + msg);
          }
        );
    });
  }
}
```

It shows all products, so 40 Objects :
 [image]

How can I loop through all Objects so that I can pick the "Name" like this example:

```
public LocationGUID() {
    return this.config["LocationGuid"];
}
```

The example above will return the "LocationGuid" from the Object. This is easy because there is only 1 Object that is returned, but now I need it for 40 objects! 
Someone please help :D

Comment: Did you try looping through your array using *ngFor directive ?

Comment: hi @faizan, I have tried that but I cant make it work correctly. Could you show me how I can use *ngFor directive correctly in my situation?

Comment: You need to share the HTML also, normally we can *ngFor on a DOM element something like this.

*ngFor="let value of values" and inside the element we can access value using interpolation as {{value.name}}

upload your code on stackblitz if possible

Comment: You may have to use the `async` pipe when using *ngFor with your data, something like `<div *ngFor="let c of config | async">{{ c?.LocationGuid }}</div>`

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more about what you want to achieve? I posted an answer, but without more information its hard to guess if the code makes sense...

Comment: I replied to you @ManuelManhart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through before the resolve. But I am not sure that this is the cleanest solution for what you really want to achieve.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { KioskService } from "./kiosk.service";
import { Object } from "../object";

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private config: Object = {};
    // CHANGE (names are added in this array)
    private names: Object = [];
    public domainSettings: Object = {};

    constructor(private http: Http, private kioskservice: KioskService) {}

    public getAllProducts() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http
            .get(
            `${this.kioskservice.getAPIUrl()}products/?apikey=${this.kioskservice.getAPIKey()}`
            )
            .toPromise()
            .then(
            res => {
                this.config = res.json();
                console.log(res.json());
                // CHANGE (add names)
                if (this.config && this.config.length) {
                    this.names = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.config.length; i++) {
                        this.names.push(this.config[i]['Name']);
                    }
                }
                resolve();
            },
            msg => {
                throw new Error("Couldn't get all Bookings: " + msg);
            }
            );
        });
    }

    // CHANGE (function to fetch the names)
    public getNames() {
        return this.names;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, What I want to achieve is that I loop thought each object and take the "Name" from it and save it in a function. Like the 

public LocationGUID() {
    return this.config["LocationGuid"];
}

Comment: The code you wrote for me, works. I can console.log(this.names) and it will show me all 40 names of the products!!

Comment: But how can I save it in a function like the LocationGuid

Comment: @MexLataster I updated my answer. 1. I am still not sure this is clean code. 2. Please do not forget to accept the answer if it helped you to achieve what you desire.

Comment: @ManuelManhart if you wanted it cleaner the first obvious thing would be to remove the redundant calls to `new Promise()` and `resolve()`: the chain `this.http().toPromise().then(...)` is already a promise so the code can just return that value.